# CORS error when posting data to my DRF API from a template within the project itself

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I have a Django project that has an end-point created using DRF. I am posting data to it from a template within the project itself (another rendered view). However, I get the following error code:

```
403 Unauthorized. CSRF token not provided.
```

This makes no sense because both the end-point and the view shares the same origin. So why am I getting this error? And how can I solve this issue? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to do what it says: provide csrf token. 
Use this function to get it from cookies:

```
export function getCookie(name){
  let cookieValue = null;
  if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
      var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
      for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
          var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
          if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
              cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
              break;
          }
      }
  }
  return cookieValue;
}
```

Then modify your ajax function like so:

```
const csrf_token = this.getCookie('csrftoken')
const postData = async() => {
              ... 
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'x-csrftoken': csrf_token
      }
              ...
}
```